# Dropdown not expanding in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on making `dropdown` in `bootstrap`. When I click on dropdown that is not getting expanded. Looks like missing bootstrap references. My code

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="dropdown">
  <!--Trigger-->
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown"
    aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Material dropdown</button>
    
  <!--Menu-->
  <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-primary">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have installed bootstrap using `ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap` command from VS code terminal. I got this code from [here](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/components/dropdowns/). `packgae.json` contains this

```
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^6.1.0",
"bootstrap": "^4.4.0",
```

How can I get `dropdown` work?

Comment: can you try creating demo on stackblitz ?

Comment: I can but I can't save code anywhere like git. Does that work by giving simply url?

Comment: @Allabakash please check this demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zm8tkb

Comment: use ng-bootstrap instead of bootstrap dropdown.  here is an example https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are making use of ng-bootstrap, you can use dropdown component as mentioned in their docs.
you need to import only boostrap.css in index.html, you no need to add any other dependency other than "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^6.1.0".

here is the demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mzkkg6

here is the doc reference - https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/examples

Answer (score 1):

Hey @Arvind Chourasiya can you please try this that will work as you expect.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Material dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Please check at here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-w2ch26

Hope this will help you. thanks

Comment: @Arvind Chourasiya i have added snippet can you please check.

Comment: here working I saw. In my editor VS code dropdown not expanding when I am clicking on it. What packages do I need to install?

Comment: Can you please share code in `http://jsfiddle.net/`

Comment: Is that possible for you to check here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zm8tkb

Comment: @Arvind Chourasiya Thanks for update in `https://stackblitz.com/`. I have update it and it is working now please check at `https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-w2ch26`

Comment: What changes you have done there, know you please let know?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217295/discussion-between-chintan-kotadiya-and-arvind-chourasiya).